# What order does the sshd_config files use values for the settings MACs and Ciphers?

Tags: linux, ssh, configuration

I am currently using MACs and Ciphers in my sshd_config. We have these settings being scanned for vulnerabilities.

I would like to know if the order of these settings matters at all?
Currently, they are:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512
Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr
```

Does this behave any differently:

```
MACs hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-256
Ciphers aes256-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes128-ctr
```

If the values for the settings are moved around into a different order does that matter?
If it does matter can you possibly link some documentation on your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the order differs since both `MACs` and `Ciphers` will set the allowed and order of preference.

From `ssh_config` manpage:

> Ciphers
>
> Specifies the ciphers allowed and their order of preference.  Multiple ciphers must be comma-separated.  If the specified list begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified ciphers will be appended to the default set instead of replacing them.  If the specified list begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified ciphers (including wildcards) will be removed from the default set instead of replacing them.  If the specified list begins with a ‘^’ character, then the specified ciphers will be placed at the head of the default set.

> MACs
>
> Specifies the MAC (message authentication code) algorithms in order of
> preference.  The MAC algorithm is used for data integrity protection.
> Multiple algorithms must be comma-separated.  If the specified list
> begins with a ‘+’ character, then the specified algorithms will be
> appended to the default set instead of replacing them.  If the
> specified list begins with a ‘-’ character, then the specified
> algorithms (including wild‐cards) will be removed from the default set
> instead of replacing them.  If the specified list begins with a ‘^’
> character, then the specified algorithms will be placed at the head of
> the default set.

Although, since they are set as preferred orders, it will not prevent a client from having a different preference for negotiation, nor any `Cipher` or `MAC` missing.